# How many UML diagrams are essential to describe a complete system?

Tags: uml

Is it essential to have all 9 diagrams of UML to describe a system?

I know that sequence and collaboration diagram are isomorphic so one can be eliminated here, Is it OK if i represent it by only one diagram for dynamic part and one diagram for static part?

Comment: It's very subjective. Depending on how far along the system is in development, you may only be able to create two or three. If this is a system that you're going back and making diagrams for, you could have dozens depending on complexity. Different diagrams explain different things. What are you wanting to explain? Are there a lot of use cases? Is the your state machine complex and could benefit from additional diagrams? There's no 1 right answer for a given system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually UML 2.x has 14 diagrams.

**But you do not have to use all diagrams in order to describe your system.**

As a general  advice:

> Model and apply the UML for the smaller percentage of unusual,
>   difficult, tricky part of your design space [ Larman, Applying UML and
>   patterns]

Before drawing a UML diagram ask yourself : Why am I drawing this diagram? What is my real purpose? What kind of benefit will it give me? If you do not have solid answer or benefit, just do not draw any diagram.

Use UML diagrams for understanding nature of your problem-solution space,to explore your problem space , to explore new design ideas,to communicate ideas with team members,  but **not for just documentation.**

> So technically it is okay to have just  two diagrams: one  static
>   diagram like class diagram and a dynamic diagram like a sequence
>   diagram.

**But technically correct does not mean it is the right thing to do**

All diagrams should have a purpose-benefit for to draw it.Otherwise it will be not a modelling activity. It will be drawing exercise :-)

Use small number of diagrams which gives you most benefit-help you while developing your system.

Do not forget that the important thing is not drawing UML diagram. The important thing is  finding right abstractions, assigning right-balanced responsibilities to objects, making your system flexible and extensible.

**Finally**

No UML diagrams can make your design  "innocent-sinless". All design ideas that  are on papers are  "guilty", until their "innocence" is proven by working code. :-)